# Set poster image mobile HTML 5 video

Tags: css, html, video

We have a HTML5 video on our webpageheader. The poster we set for the video is accurate for desktop but not for mobile. Is it possible to set a different poster only shown on certain viewports/mobile devices?

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="1" poster="/test6.jpg">
  <source src="/VideoHeader2.0.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: The image set as a poster always conforms to the video tag's dimensions, so adjust the video tag.

Comment: Yeah but we want to show a different image on mobile

Comment: matchMedia API to detect the screen change and simple JavaScript. If you post your JavaScript/jQuery I can help you.